# Print exact value represented by float in [0,1)

Tags: python, reinventing-the-wheel

Motivated by yet another [floating point question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64013665/14265373) on stackoverflow, I decided to print a float value \$x\in[0,1)\$, i.e., the fractional part of a float (I might try printing whole floats later). But not the rounded value like `print(x)` does but the exact represented value. And only using basic operations:

```
def print_float(x):

    # Convert float x to integer fraction num/den.
    num, den = 0, 1
    while x:
        x *= 2
        num *= 2
        den *= 2
        if x >= 1:
            x -= 1
            num += 1

    # Print num/den in decimal.
    print('0.', end='')
    while num:
        num *= 10
        print(num // den, end='')
        num %= den
    print()
```

Testing it against a simpler way using string formatting:

```
from random import random

for _ in range(3):
    x = random()
    print(f'{x}:')
    print(('%.2000f' % x).rstrip('0'))
    print_float(x)
    print()
```

Output:

```
0.1659451324370237:
0.16594513243702369020837750213104300200939178466796875
0.16594513243702369020837750213104300200939178466796875

0.6127401513193578:
0.6127401513193577731186678647645749151706695556640625
0.6127401513193577731186678647645749151706695556640625

0.11658146732832175:
0.11658146732832175285210496440413407981395721435546875
0.11658146732832175285210496440413407981395721435546875
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Separation of Concerns

Your function is doing too much.  It is:

1. Converting the float to a fraction
2. Converting the fraction to a string of digits
3. Printing the string of digits

You should separate these.

## Float to Fraction

First, let's move the float-to-fraction code into its own function.

```py
from typing import Tuple

def float_to_fraction(value: float) -> Tuple[int, int]:
    """
    Convert a floating point number in the range [0, 1) into a fraction.

    >>> float_to_fraction(0.625)
    (5, 8)

    >>> float_to_fraction(0.1)
    (3602879701896397, 36028797018963968)
    """

    if not (0 <= value < 1):
        raise ValueError("Value out of range (0 <= value < 1)")
    
    numerator, denominator = 0, 1
    while value:
        value *= 2
        numerator *= 2
        denominator *= 2
        if value >= 1:
            value -= 1
            numerator += 1
    return numerator, denominator
```

Here, I've added:

- type hints, describing the input and output types for the function,
- a `"""docstring"""` describing how to use the function,

  - including an example formatted for use with the [`doctest`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/doctest.html) module,
- input range validation, since your expectation is for the range to be within a narrow range of `float` values.

I've also changed `num` to `numerator`, since it would be easy to misinterpret the abbreviation to mean `number`.  Similarity, `den` became `denominator` and `x` became `value`.

## Fraction to String

Again, converting a numerator/denominator fraction into a series of digits is logical unit of code, which could be reused elsewhere, so I've made it into a function:

```py
def fraction_to_string(numerator: int, denominator: int) -> str:
    """
    Convert a proper fraction into a corresponding series of digits.

    >>> fraction_to_string(5, 8)
    '0.625'
    """

    if not (0 <= numerator < denominator):
        raise ValueError("Improper or negative fraction given")

    if denominator & (denominator - 1) != 0:
        raise ValueError("Denominator must be a power of 2")

    digits = '0.'
    while numerator:
        numerator *= 10
        digits += str(numerator // denominator)
        numerator %= denominator

    return digits
```

Note: `str(0.0)` returns `'0.0'` but your code (and my duplication of it here) returns `'0.'`.

Your code originally guaranteed the denominator was a power of 2.  With this new function, a caller could ask for `fraction_to_digits(1, 3)` which would be an infinitely long string of digits, so I've added a condition restricting the denominator to a power of 2.

## Float to String

Now we can compose these two functions, as well as recreate the original function's functionality:

```py
def float_to_string(value: float) -> str:
    numerator, denominator = float_to_fraction(value)
    return fraction_to_string(numerator, denominator)

def print_float(x):
    print(float_to_string(x))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod(verbose=True)

    from random import random

    for _ in range(3):
        x = random()
        print(f'{x}:')
        print(('%.2000f' % x).rstrip('0'))
        print_float(x)
        print()
```

Additionally, I've added a "main guard" (always a good idea), and I've added a call to [`doctest.testmod()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/doctest.html?highlight=testmod#doctest.testmod) so the tests embedded in the `"""docstrings"""` are executed.

## Notes

The function `float_to_fraction(value)` may be replaced by the built-in function [`value.as_integer_ratio()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=as_integer_ratio#float.as_integer_ratio).

```py
>>> value = 0.625
>>> value.as_integer_ratio()
(5, 8)
```

Comment: Thanks. Nice improvements. Didn't know it's that easy to run doctests. `fraction_to_string` *could* handle denominators other than powers of 2, like 7/25 or 7/28 would also work. The exact rule might be that after simplifying the fraction, the denominator's only prime factors are 2 and 5. But yeah, for my purpose I don't mind simply requiring powers of 2.